# once yes, twice maybe, thrice no

Tags: word

> When it occurs once, it is __.
>
> When it occurs twice, it probably is __.
>
> When it occurs thrice, it is not __.

What is it?

Not a [wordplay](/questions/tagged/wordplay) puzzle. Just a simple one.

Comment: I don't think this is a *good* question (since the answer is pretty much obvious, at least to me), but I also don't think it's primarily opinion-based, precisely because it has a single obvious solution ("mistake", as suggested by manshu, doesn't really work IMO). Voting to reopen.

Comment: There's a single obvious solution, but it isn't really a very satisfactory solution: plenty of things could occur 3x and still be _____, and not everything that occurs only once is ______. And (especially in view of the "... three times is enemy action" quotation) it's a bit too *straightforward*: here are some well known properties of X, now find X. I didn't VTC but I don't think I'll VTR either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps nikamed is thinking of

> chance

or

> coincidence

or something of the kind? (I don't find either a super-convincing answer, I have to say, but somehow the question gives the impression that there may not be a super-convincing answer...)

Comment: Here it is. Thanks for saving me from too broads. The coincidence was what I was thinking.

Comment: Good answer (+1), but I'd like to point out that things can happen by coincidence 3 times, and something that happens once isn't necessarily chance, so the question doesn't really work

Comment: That's why I don't find it super-convincing :-).

Comment: [Goldfinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldfinger_(novel)#cite_ref-FOOTNOTEFleming2006222-223_1-1): "Once is happenstance, twice is coincidence, three times is enemy action."

Comment: @DanRussell Yes!! That was the one which I was trying to remember...

Answer (score 3):

The clear answer is a

> Mistake

Because

> Mistakes can happen once or twice but not every time.

Comment: Not the answer I thought but +1

Comment: @nikamed: This means your question is too broad.

Comment: @Deusovi I totally agree.

Comment: Wait for downvotes @nikamed

Comment: I don't think a mistake can't happen three times... Therefore I'm not sure if this is a valid answer and if it is really too broad.

Comment: @nikamed Close vote would be a better thing to wait.

Comment: [Actually, it can](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/94520-everything-that-happens-once-can-never-happen-again-but-everything) ;)